# How to present an UIViewController like an actionSheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to present a view that only occupies the bottom half of the screen, with the background view remaining visible with no possible interaction.

Just like an `UIAlertContoller` with the `actionSheet` style.

How to do that in Swift ?

Comment: You could instantiate and add the newViewController's view as a subview to your currentViewController with frame.origin.y = size of screen and then animate that go-up move

Comment: It's not swift, but try adjusting the animation from this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17792844/2535467 so that it animates from bottom up, instead of from right - left.

Answer (score 1):

Create that view as a normal UIViewController, assign an identifier to it and then instantiate it like this: (keep it as a member variable though, you will need it)

```
var controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier") as! UIViewController
```

then you can add it to your parent view like

```
self.addSubview(controller)
```

Be careful about positioning it though, you can animate it neatly to the middle of the screen like

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    controller.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2
})
 in
```

But the initial positioning should be made the holding view's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, like

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    controller.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
}
```

because in `viewDidLoad` the views don't really have correct frames yet and it would end up in wrong position